# Can't list directory even as root?

Tags: permissions, osx

I'm running into an odd issue on my Mac (macOS 10.14.3). I ran `sudo du -xk /` to get detailed data on my disk usage, and ran into several errors:

```
du: /Users/brx/Library/Application Support/MobileSync: Operation not permitted
du: /Users/brx/Library/Application Support/CallHistoryTransactions: Operation not permitted
du: /Users/brx/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC: Operation not permitted
du: /Users/brx/Library/Application Support/CallHistoryDB: Operation not permitted
du: /Users/brx/Library/IdentityServices: Operation not permitted
du: /Users/brx/Library/Messages: Operation not permitted
du: /Users/brx/Library/HomeKit: Operation not permitted
du: /Users/brx/Library/Mail: Operation not permitted
du: /Users/brx/Library/Safari: Operation not permitted
du: /Users/brx/Library/Suggestions: Operation not permitted
du: /Users/brx/Library/Containers/com.apple.VoiceMemos: Operation not permitted
du: /Users/brx/Library/Containers/com.apple.Home: Operation not permitted
du: /Users/brx/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari: Operation not permitted
du: /Users/brx/Library/Containers/com.apple.iChat: Operation not permitted
du: /Users/brx/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail: Operation not permitted
du: /Users/brx/Library/Containers/com.apple.news: Operation not permitted
du: /Users/brx/Library/Containers/com.apple.stocks: Operation not permitted
du: /Users/brx/Library/PersonalizationPortrait: Operation not permitted
du: /Users/brx/Library/Metadata/CoreSpotlight: Operation not permitted
du: /Users/brx/Library/Metadata/com.apple.IntelligentSuggestions: Operation not permitted
du: /Users/brx/Library/Cookies: Operation not permitted
du: /Users/brx/Library/Caches/com.apple.safaridavclient: Operation not permitted
du: /Users/brx/Library/Caches/com.apple.HomeKit.configurations: Operation not permitted
du: /Users/brx/Library/Caches/CloudKit/com.apple.Safari: Operation not permitted
du: /Users/brx/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari: Operation not permitted
du: /Users/brx/Library/Caches/com.apple.homed: Operation not permitted
```

This is strange because I should have permissions to these directories even without `sudo`. If I open them in Finder, I can see the contents fine, but in Terminal:

```
~/Library/Caches$ ls -la com.apple.homed/
ls: : Operation not permitted
~/Library/Caches$ sudo ls -la com.apple.homed/
ls: : Operation not permitted
~/Library/Caches$ ls -lade@ com.apple.homed/
drwxr-xr-x  7 brx  staff  224 Mar 18 14:36 com.apple.homed/
```

So there's no ACLs nor extended attributes. I own the directory so I should be able to list it!

Yet if I do `open /Users/brx/Library/Caches/com.apple.homed/`, a Finder window pops up with the contents (three files `Cache.db{,-shm,-wal}` and a directory called `fsCachedData`).

What's going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that it is macOS's SIP ([System Integrity Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection)) that stops the `du` and `ls` processes from accessing the files/directories, even when running as root.  SIP appears to be, since macOS Mojave, active for a number of locations under `~/Library`, which means that only trusted applications can access them.

I added my terminal application (iTerm2) to the list of applications that should be granted "Full Disk Access", and I did that in the "Security & Privacy" Systems Preferences settings, under the "Privacy" tab.  This seems to have solved it for me.  I say "seems" as I'm no macOS expert, but I believe this is what made me able to access everything under `~/Library`.

Apple recommends *not* turning off SIP globally on the system, for obvious reasons, and I don't see a real reason to do so either.

Comment: Interesting. What surprises me is that Finder has access to these directories by default - I'd expect them to block access to any unrelated apps.

Comment: @nneonneo It may be that Finder is simply assumed to be "a trusted application".